# Android Studio Git: login screen checked as Remember with wrong password

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, repository

I can not access my project in Git because I entered an erroneous password with the box marked (remember), this has caused that the login window no longer appears and therefore the user always invalidates me. I need to access from the Android Studio to clone my project is a requirement.

[Login screen image Invalid user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw277.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials (to left of screen) -> Windows credentials -> Now change your git credentials